# Как объединить две кнопки используя if

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть `button` Play и `button` Pause. Хочу объединить их в одну кнопку, чтобы когда композиция уже играет при нажатии ставилась пауза, а если стоит пауза то при нажатии композиция продолжалась. При разных попытках получалась ерунда. Подскажите как объединить.

```
private void button_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((list_catalog.Items.Count != 0) && (list_catalog.SelectedIndex != -1))
        {
            string current = Vars.Files[list_catalog.SelectedIndex];
            Vars.CurrentTrackNumber = list_catalog.SelectedIndex;
            BassLike.Play(current, BassLike.Volume);
            label_time1.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
            label_time2.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
            xrewind.Maximum = BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
            xrewind.Value = BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }



private void button_pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BassLike.Pause();
    }
```

Comment: Самый простой вариант - используйте переменную-флаг `bool Paused`. Если она равна `true`, то меняете её значение на `false` и выполняете действия, которые должны выполняться при нажатии на `Play`. Если переменная равна 'false' - меняете значение на `true` и вызываете код, выполняемый при нажатии кнопки `Pause`. Ниже вам дали ответ с аналогичным подходом )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private bool playing = false;

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (playing)
    {
        BassLike.Pause();
        playing = false;
        return;
    } 

    if ((list_catalog.Items.Count != 0) && (list_catalog.SelectedIndex != -1))
    {
        string current = Vars.Files[list_catalog.SelectedIndex];
        Vars.CurrentTrackNumber = list_catalog.SelectedIndex;
        BassLike.Play(current, BassLike.Volume);
        label_time1.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
        label_time2.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
        xrewind.Maximum = BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
        xrewind.Value = BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        playing = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: if (!playing) ?

Comment: знаю, знаю, уже исправил :)

Comment: уже проголосовал :)

Comment: То же что и у меня. Когда композиция на паузе и я нажимаю еще раз для воспроизведения, то играть начинает почему-то с начала, а не с позиции паузы.

Comment: Даже на паузу не становится, а просто начинает играть с начала.

Comment: я честно говоря проигрыватели никогда не писал, но выглядит так, будто ета строчка "BassLike.Play(current, BassLike.Volume);" запускает композицию с момента current, возможно ету переменную стоит апдейтить когда ставим паузу

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Что Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: я имею в виду, чтото такое :
if (playing)
    {
        BassLike.Pause();
        playing = false;
        current = "текущая позиция проигрывания";
        return;
    }

Comment: И все равно не получается. current - не существует в текущем контексте. Но это вроде поправил строчкой: string current = Vars.Files[list_catalog.SelectedIndex];. Что дальше не понимаю.

Comment: ну смотрете, деталей реализации вашего проигрывателя я не знаю, но задумка такова : жмем "играть", композиция начинает играть с начал, потом жмем "пауза" композиция останавливаеться на какомто моменте, какуюто инфу о том, где именно остановилис (на какой секунде или чтото такое) сохраняем в какуюто переменную к примеру, и в будущем начинать проигрывать будем уже с етой отметки

Comment: Может есть метод `BassLike.Resume(...);`?